# Reading deserialized json throw null reference

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net, deserialization

While i'm able to deserialize the json into an object (or at least there is no error) everytime that i attempt to read the data it throw a null reference exception. 
Here's the json:

```
{
 "38308613": [
{
  "name": "Cassiopeia's Mercenaries",
  "tier": "GOLD",
  "queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
  "entries": [
    {
      "playerOrTeamId": "38308613",
      "playerOrTeamName": "TrashTheBrain",
      "division": "III",
      "leaguePoints": 75,
      "wins": 328,
      "losses": 321,
      "isHotStreak": false,
      "isVeteran": true,
      "isFreshBlood": false,
      "isInactive": false
    }
  ]
},
{
  "name": "Cho'Gath's Shadowdancers",
  "tier": "GOLD",
  "queue": "RANKED_TEAM_3x3",
  "entries": [
    {
      "playerOrTeamId": "TEAM-8bf3a360-77ba-11e4-9fc4-c81f66db96d8",
      "playerOrTeamName": "Ebal 9 vas",
      "division": "IV",
      "leaguePoints": 0,
      "wins": 22,
      "losses": 24,
      "isHotStreak": false,
      "isVeteran": false,
      "isFreshBlood": false,
      "isInactive": false
    }
  ]
},
{
  "name": "Elise's Deceivers",
  "tier": "BRONZE",
  "queue": "RANKED_TEAM_5x5",
  "entries": [
    {
      "playerOrTeamId": "TEAM-8bf3a360-77ba-11e4-9fc4-c81f66db96d8",
      "playerOrTeamName": "Ebal 9 vas",
      "division": "III",
      "leaguePoints": 66,
      "wins": 5,
      "losses": 6,
      "isHotStreak": false,
      "isVeteran": false,
      "isFreshBlood": false,
      "isInactive": false
    }
  ]
},
{
  "name": "Vayne's Snipers",
  "tier": "SILVER",
  "queue": "RANKED_TEAM_3x3",
  "entries": [
    {
      "playerOrTeamId": "TEAM-7da3b7b0-7bfa-11e5-a148-c81f66dd30e5",
      "playerOrTeamName": "MathMechPower",
      "division": "V",
      "leaguePoints": 75,
      "wins": 7,
      "losses": 6,
      "isHotStreak": false,
      "isVeteran": false,
      "isFreshBlood": false,
      "isInactive": false
    }
  ]
  }
  ],
 "65100402": [
{
  "name": "Jarvan IV's Spellslingers",
  "tier": "GOLD",
  "queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
  "entries": [
    {
      "playerOrTeamId": "65100402",
      "playerOrTeamName": "Charlynnnn",
      "division": "I",
      "leaguePoints": 8,
      "wins": 447,
      "losses": 438,
      "isHotStreak": false,
      "isVeteran": true,
      "isFreshBlood": false,
      "isInactive": false
    }
  ]
},
{
  "name": "Darius's Warlocks",
  "tier": "SILVER",
  "queue": "RANKED_TEAM_3x3",
  "entries": [
    {
      "playerOrTeamId": "TEAM-f86481d0-6cf2-11e5-a39d-c81f66dd30e5",
      "playerOrTeamName": "YingYangWolves",
      "division": "II",
      "leaguePoints": 0,
      "wins": 4,
      "losses": 2,
      "isHotStreak": false,
      "isVeteran": false,
      "isFreshBlood": false,
      "isInactive": false
    }
  ]
},
{
  "name": "Morgana's Elementalists",
  "tier": "SILVER",
  "queue": "RANKED_TEAM_5x5",
  "entries": [
    {
      "playerOrTeamId": "TEAM-f86481d0-6cf2-11e5-a39d-c81f66dd30e5",
      "playerOrTeamName": "YingYangWolves",
      "division": "III",
      "leaguePoints": 0,
      "wins": 3,
      "losses": 3,
      "isHotStreak": false,
      "isVeteran": false,
      "isFreshBlood": false,
      "isInactive": false
    }
  ]
}
]
}
```

And the class used to deserialize the json:

```
Public Class Entry
    Public Property playerOrTeamId As String
    Public Property playerOrTeamName As String
    Public Property division As String
    Public Property leaguePoints As Integer
    Public Property wins As Integer
    Public Property losses As Integer
    Public Property isHotStreak As Boolean
    Public Property isVeteran As Boolean
    Public Property isFreshBlood As Boolean
    Public Property isInactive As Boolean
End Class

    Public Class PlayerID
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property tier As String
    Public Property queue As String
    Public Property entries As Entry()
End Class

Public Class Example
    Public Property PlayerID As PlayerID()
End Class
```

I tried to deserialize using the code:

```
 Dim output As New PlayerID 
    output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Example)(TextBox1.Text)

    For Each i In output.PlayerID 
        MsgBox(i.name)
    Next
```

Also i tried to turn the Example class to List(Of PlayerId) but still the null reference is there.

So could anyone point the correct way to deserialize and loop through the properties? No matter what i try json is not my thing.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you deserialized to `output`.  `Example` is a type name; its `PlayerID()` array will always be null/Nothing

Comment: @Plutonix You are right on that but sadly it's a typo. I will fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an entire tier in your classes.  `"38308613"` for example is an array holding the 4 teams (??) between the following `[ ... ]`.  The same for "65100402".  The root object, then contains those 2 things, but yours tries to define them as one big array.  (Content wise it looks like it is jumbled with those two teams mistakenly containing other teams, but since that is how it is structured, thats the way it will deserialize).

Since the root object ("Example") is really just the very first `{` and last `}`, it is often easier to just get rid of them.  So, to deserialize:

```
Dim jstr = ...from where ever

Dim result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, PlayerID()))(jstr)
```

The result will be a Dictionary with "38308613" and "65100402" as the keys.  The first holds 4 teams(?) the last one holds 3.  "Cassiopeia's Mercenaries" would be:

```
result("38308613")(0).name
```

The name from the first (0th) PlayerID from the "38308613" collection.  To iterate the results:

```
' print all team  names
For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, PlayerID()) In result
    Console.WriteLine("This group: {0}", kvp.Key)
    For Each p As PlayerID In kvp.Value
        Console.WriteLine(p.name)
    Next
    Console.WriteLine()
Next
```

Output:

> This group: 38308613
>   Cassiopeia's Mercenaries
>   Cho'Gath's Shadowdancers
>   Elise's Deceivers
>   Vayne's Snipers
>   etc

Comment: well your answer makes me feel relief and shame at the same time! It's the second time that you give me an awesome answer  (last time was about 9 months ago,). I just don't understand json AT ALL while you make it seem so easy. Thanks buddy you are awesome! By the way those teams are actually stupid names i'm only after the tier/points property to match them with rest player data and then display them as an overlay using DirectX over the game window.

Comment: Glad to help.  Now that you can upvote feel free to do so